# CSS animate property not working with position element

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
.spinnerWrapper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}

.spinner {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  animation: spinner 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
  }
  25% {
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
  }
  /* 100% {
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
  } */
}
```

```html
 <div class="spinnerWrapper">
        <div class="spinner"></div>
 </div>
```

I am not sure why its not working.

on commenting 100% its working correct for 0%, 25% and 50% but when I use 100% its just show animation between 0% and 100%

anyone can suggest why its not working.

**Note:**  On using below animation its working correctly but I am not able to understand why above case is not working properly

```
@keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  25% {
    left: 90px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 90px;
    top: 90px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
    top: 90px;
  }
}
```

Comment: `top` and `bottom` are two different properties which do quite different things. You cannot interpolate between two different properties. Same for `left` and `right`.

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+css+transition+position+top+bottom) of [Changing bottom and top values in a CSS transition on click](/q/30102844/4642212).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to animate between positions, but top and bottom (and left and right) are different properties. So the blue ball jumps around.

I'm assuming in this snippet that you want the ball to travel smoothly (let me know if I've misunderstood) so it animates the same property each time, left and top.

The only slightly tricky thing is if we animate to left: 100% the ball will go outside the yellow box, we want it to stay inside so use a CSS calc to get the correct coordinate.

```css
.spinnerWrapper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}

.spinner {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  animation: spinner 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
  }
  25% {
    top: 0px;
    left: calc(100% - 10px);
  }
  50% {
    left: calc(100% - 10px);
    top: calc(100% - 10px);
  }
  75% {
    left: 0px;
    top: calc(100% - 10px);
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinnerWrapper">
  <div class="spinner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can combine with transform to avoid fixed value: https://jsfiddle.net/8v0bmaqL/

Comment: @temaniafif Yes, you are quite right - and that's better really. I actually started putting translate in then decided it was a bit complex when trying to explain about left and right as it brings in another factor - but it's certainly better/more general to use the translate.